# Как перевести консоль во весь экран, а потом наоборот С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Как открыть консоль в полноэкранный режим, а потом перевести в нормальный размер?

Comment: нажать alt-enter?

Comment: хорошо, а как реализовать программно(код)

Comment: А зачем ? И ещё 6 символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз нажимать Alt-enter не хочется, можно нажать его программно

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  ::SendMessage(::GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0x20000000);
  //..
}
```

Вообще то должен ещё такой способ работать, но мне не удалось его заставить

```
SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
```

Comment: Отлично! А как восстановить размер?

Comment: ну подумайте немного. Если повторное нажание Alt-enter исправляет?

Comment: Да, Вы совершенно правы. Логика!